# Only have separators between UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a table view for my app that looks similar to the stock alarm clock app, but I'm not sure how they managed to only have separators between the alarms while leaving the rest of the tableview blank.

Here's what I mean:

[image: Alarm clock app - no separators after last alarm]

my app

[image: My app - separators after last alarm]

It's probably something simple, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to hide the empty cells , then call the following line in ViewDidLoad

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

or use

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

if you want to hide the seperator line, then call the following line in ViewDidLoad

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Either st the tableview to grouped style, or add the separators on the cells and set the table separators to none or transparent

Answer (score -1):

You can set the separator color same as the back ground color for the unpopulated entries.